# Is this a valid redirect statement?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I am trying to redirect to page using php with the '?' operator to get the id in the next page, is this the correct statement to do so? I am being redirected to the page but the url shows : http://localhost/mysql/welcome.php only.

Where am i going wrong?

here's the statement:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
     window.location = "../mysql/welcome.php?id='.$id.'";
      -->
     </script>';
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use `header("Location: /mysql/welcome.php?id=$id")`?

Comment: Some browsers don't show the query string in the address bar, unless you focus it.

Comment: Yes, it's valid.  Wise: maybe not.  Valid: yes. ;)

Comment: Try to avoid the client side redirection in any way, always use the server side.

Comment: Any web crawler/spider will not follow this redirect. You should really do a server-side redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's valid but HTML comments aren't needed:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">    
     window.location = "../mysql/welcome.php?id='.$id.'";    
     </script>';
```

But I would do this server side though:

```
header("Location: ../mysql/welcome.php?id=$id");
```

Comment: yet i am unable to redirect using 

header("Location: ../mysql/welcome.php?id=".$id);

the url is still localhost/mysql/welcome.php

Comment: @user1373168 replace it with an absolute url

Answer (score 0):

If you are in PHP context why don't you use this:

```
header("Location: /mysql/welcome.php?id=$id");
```

If you insist on using that `echo` with javascript, the correct way will be:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">    
        window.location = "../mysql/welcome.php?id='.$id.'";    
      </script>';
```

Comment: yet i am unable to redirect using header("Location: ../mysql/welcome.php?id=".$id); the url is still localhost/mysql/welcome.php